# How to change the Struts2 validation error message in the case of an invalid field value?

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2

I'm using Struts2 validation on a web form.  In the case that a field is suppose to be an integer or Date, the `<s:fielderror>` message I receive is a generic `Invalid field value for field "[fieldname]"`  Naturally, I want to customize this for the user.

Here's an example validation:

```
<field name="spouseDOB">
    <field-validator type="date">
        <message>"Spouse Date of Birth" is invalid.</message>
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="date">
        <param name="min">01/01/1900</param>
        <message>"Spouse Date of Birth" must be after 1900 AD.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

The message `"Spouse Date of Birth" is invalid.` never appears, for any invalid date that I have tried.  The output is the generic `Invalid field value for field spouseDOB`

`spouseDOB` is a `java.util.Date` object in the action class.  It is set by a `<s:textfield>` in the JSP.

Comment: Well, at least I got the Tumbleweed badge for this . . .

Answer (score 8):

In your `ApplicationResources.properties` file, insert

```
invalid.fieldvalue.spouseDOB = "Spouse Date of Birth" is invalid.
```

If you don't have that file, look at [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27).

Comment: I have no way of verifying whether this answer solves this problem from last year.

Comment: yuudachi, for reference this answer is spot on.  The invalid.fieldvalue.XXX (XXX being fieldName) is the message resource key needed to overwrite the default conversionValidation error message!

Comment: Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

make one properties file in same package where your action class is defined

`"youactionclassname.properties"` file and adding error for it,

like `"invalid.fieldvalue.yourfiledname = as you want for error "` ,and do the next.

1. save it
2. and re start server
3. run

now you can see ,error was customized ....

Tell me if works

Good luck

Comment: I asked this question nearly five years ago! I've since changed jobs multiple times, and certainly don't have access to the code in question.

Answer (score -1):

Well it's missing `</message>` for one thing

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error wasn't present in the actual code.