# How to internationalize a collection's conversion error message in Struts2?

Tags: internationalization, struts2

A related problem that is specific to single field has been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555096/how-to-change-the-struts2-validation-error-message-in-the-case-of-an-invalid-fie). But how to customize a collection field's conversion error message?

Here is an example:
On a jsp page, I have a field in Collection type:

```
...
<s:iterator value="items" status="m">
<s:hidden name="selitmems[%{#m.index}].id" value="%{id}"/>
<s:textfield name="selitmems[%{#m.index}].quant" size="10"/>
</s:iterator>
```

The items' type is: `List<Item>`; the selitems' type is `List<SelItem>`.
I want selitmems[].quant property to be an integer type. If a string like "abc" is filled in for the first item by an end user, the default error message is:

> Invalid field value for field "selitmems[0].quant".

The above message is not what i want. In my case, I would prefer to generalize the error message as follows regardless of the specific selected item:

> Please input integers for the items.

Of course it would be great if the error message can vary according to the specific item:

> Please input an integer for the first item.

I have tried to add some keys like "selitmems[0].quant" or "selitmems" in the properties file, but can't get the result. Is there way to customize the error message for a collection field in struts2 when I can still reuse the built-in type conversion functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "label" attribute. You can play some... interesting games with this, such as (untested, but close):

```
label="%{getText('selitem.quantity', { #m.index })}"
```

The property file would contain:

```
selitem.quantity=Item #{0}
```

You can change the conversion error message as described [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-TypeConversionErrorHandling), although this may not be precisely what you want to do.

(I've been known to remove the conversion interceptor altogether and let either the default converters or custom converters handle conversion errors when a bad conversion also fails the field's "real" validation.)

Mm hmm... you can play some crazy games with OGNL and substituion.

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this in your properties file.

```
invalid.fieldvalue.selitmems.quant = Please input integers for the items.
```

Then `selitmems[0].quant`, `selitmems[1].quant`, `selitmems[2].quant` conversion errors all return the same message.